# Make error -- how can I fix this?

Tags: makefile

I have many C files and I have built it by Visual Studio 2005 by commandline using a makefile.
All the object files are produced correctly and the linking process also works, but the final *.exe is not produced.  At the last line, there is the error below.  I understand nothing.  Can anybody help me?

Here is the error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess((null), /link /nologo /subsystem:console /o uartsim.exe xtmpmain.obj ua
rtsim.obj fiber_driver.obj xtmp_options.obj getopt.obj D:\usr\xtensa\XtDevToolsDE\install\tools\RB-2
008.4-win32\XtensaTools\lib\iss\xtmp.lib, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make.exe: *** [uartsim.exe] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Make can not find the uartsim.exe file. Either it's not on your computer, or it's not in your PATH.

Try to locate the file, check how the file path is passed to Visual Studio (environment variable, absolute path, just the executable name). If it's just the executable name, it means that you must have it in your PATH already to make it work.

Comment: But due to the above error how does the uartsim.exe produce?
no uartsim.exe in my computer ..my aim is to produce uartsim.exe..